# Setup "My Toolbar" as the opener ribbon

Tags: content-editor, ribbon

Since I've customized the "My Toolbar" ribbon, it's a lot easier to work, having all the commands I usually need on the tab. Although, everytime I open the Content Editor page, the "Home" ribbon is opened by default.

Is there any simple and quick way to change this, so that the "My Toolbar" stays as my default ribbon?

Please keep in mind that I cannot change things like the template or any code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need this change just for yourself or for all users in the system?

Answer (score 6):

Just move `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Ribbons/Default/My` item to the first position under its parent node.

[image]

**As [Jason](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/setup-my-toolbar-as-the-opener-ribbon/12860?noredirect=1#comment19675_12860) mentioned, this will affect all the users who use Content Editor.**

You can do this by either setting the value of the `Sortorder` field to e.g. `-1000`:
[image]

Or by using `First` button:

[image]

or by simply drag and dropping your item before the `Home` item

Comment: It should be noted that this will change the setup for all users and the My Toolbar will be the default for every user who logs in.

Comment: Valid point. I edited my answer. Thanks Jason!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answers! 
Although, I needed this change only for me... is there any other way that doesn't affect all users?